# Take data returned from Azure Mobile Service and write to XML file in IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I'm charting into completely new territory on this one...

Currently, I am using Azure Mobile Services and a SQL Azure Database to store the data for my Windows Phone 8 application. Every time the application is launched, it pulls down all of the data from specific tables via some queries I've set up.

```
items = await phoneTable
    .Where(PhoneItem => PhoneItem.Publish == true)
    .OrderBy(PhoneItem => PhoneItem.FullName)
    .ToCollectionAsync();
```

However, this isn't always a great practice. I'm trying to implement a way for the data to be saved to a XML file in the `IsolatedStorage` of the application when it has been loaded.

I've already gotten some code that I think should READ the `IsolatedStorage` and search for the XML file, but I'm not sure how to download the data and then write that to `IsolatedStorage`.

```
    public static IEnumerable<Phones> GetSavedData()
    {
        IEnumerable<Phones> phones = new List<Phones>();

        try
        {
            using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                string offlineData = Path.Combine("WPTracker", "Offline");

                string offlineDataFile = Path.Combine(offlineData, "phones.xml");

                IsolatedStorageFileStream dataFile = null;

                if (store.FileExists(offlineDataFile))
                {
                    dataFile = store.OpenFile(offlineDataFile, FileMode.Open);

                    DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(IEnumerable<Phones>));

                    phones = (IEnumerable<Phones>)ser.ReadObject(dataFile);

                    dataFile.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Call RefreshPhoneItems();

                }
            }
        }
        catch (IsolatedStorageException)
        {

        }

        return phones;
    }
```

I'm using the `AzureMobileServices SDK` and `Newtonsoft.Json` to interact with the database. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ToCollectionAsync` in this case - it will return an object which is best used when binding to some UI control. Use `ToListAsync` instead, somewhat like the code below:

```
items = await phoneTable
    .Where(PhoneItem => PhoneItem.Publish == true)
    .OrderBy(PhoneItem => PhoneItem.FullName)
    .ToListAsync();

using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    string offlineData = Path.Combine("WPTracker", "Offline");
    string offlineDataFile = Path.Combine(offlineData, "phones.xml");
    IsolatedStorageFileStream dataFile = null;
    dataFile = store.OpenFile(offlineDataFile, FileMode.Create);
    DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(IEnumerable<Phones>));
    ser.WriteObject(dataFile, items);
    dataFile.Close();
}
```

Comment: @carlosfiguerira Now would I have to change how my text boxes receive the data? Currently I am just binding `items` to a `ListBox`. Would I have to bind `ListBox` to the XML file now?